# Why most services use non-root account could create logfile in /var/log?

Tags: systemd, service

I want to write a service putting log in /var/log, then I edit a xxx.service under systemd.

```
[Service]
User=xxx
Group=xxx
```

But the service throw a error that open /var/log/xxx.log the permission denied.
How do they implement write log in /var/log and the log owner is service account itself like nginx,mysql,httpd etc.
Is it implement in program or there is some configure in os?

Answer (score 1):

If you want service to be able to create log files on the fly, while creating the service, you can create a directory under `/var/log` and set the owner to service account

```
mkdir /var/log/myservice/
chown myservice:myservice /var/log/myservice/
chmod 755 /var/log/myservice/
```

For instance this is the case for nginx. After the first creation, logrotate can take care of file ownership. In centos8, `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` looks like: (see second line)

```
/var/log/nginx/*log {
    create 0664 nginx root
    daily
    rotate 10
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -USR1 `cat /run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

When you look at logfiles, you'll see only the actual log file is owned by nginx, and rotated ones by root.

```
$ ls -l /var/log/nginx/
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx root    0 Aug 29  2020 access.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root 3441 Aug 27  2020 access.log-20200829.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nginx root    0 Aug 29  2020 error.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root  658 Aug 27  2020 error.log-20200829.gz
```

If you want files to be directly in `/var/log`, again you'd have to create them once as root and set owner.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, I will name a few:

- create a subdirectory (`/var/log/serviceXXX` ) which is being owned by the user / group in question, and put your logfiles there
- talk to the syslog daemon, and let that daemon write the logs for you (that is what that daemon is being made for - this should be as easy as opening `/dev/log` for writing...)
- you can even configure the syslog daemon to write to the custom logfile you want, all you need for this is to create a custom logging facility (f.e. a drop-in config file in `/etc/rsyslog.d`)
- `/var/log` is owned by a specific group (`syslog` in my case) - add that group to the supplementary groups of your user